# The Meta > Users > Participation page only shows nine users

Tags: support, meta, users, users-page

While I was looking for the user id of the Community Managers / Employees while doing the search/research for posting a question here on Meta, I noticed that only nine users are shown:

[image: Meta Participation]

Why occurs this?

Comment: It was closed as "no longer reproduced" because now the Users > Participation shows week, month, quarter, year and all views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tooltip tells you why:

[image]

So only 9 users posted, voted on, commented on, or edited something here in the last 60 days.

Comment: Related (Meta SE) [How is meta participation calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145151/289691)